# SAP Test Data Container and TOSCA

Tags: tosca, sap-solution-manager

There are a couple of things that I'd like to know:

1. Can I import test data from an excel sheet to SAP Test Data Container (SOLMAN)
2. How to connect to SAP Test Data Container (SOLMAN) from Tricentis TOSCA